# How to create custom item reader in spring batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

In my app I am using sqlProcessor as database framework: https://github.com/hudec/sql-processor/wiki.

so when I want to read list of object I call:

```
List<MyClass> myClassList = myClassDao.list(...)
```

How should I iterate over this list in itemReader or how should I create my custom item reader which read data from database using sqlProcessor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an [ItemReaderAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/adapter/ItemReaderAdapter.html).
From Javadoc:
`Invokes a custom method on a delegate plain old Java object which itself provides an item.`

```
<bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.adapter.ItemReaderAdapter">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="myClassDao" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="list" />
    <property name="arguments">
      <list>
        <!-- add arguments list -->
      </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myClassDao" class="path.to.MyClassDAO" /
```

If you have special condition, arguments and other needs you can create your own ItemReader, but you can extends `ItemReaderAdapter` to reuse your DAO and save time.

Comment: hm this seems very nice but method list has some parameter. How should I add them to this reader

Answer (score 5):

You just need to implement the ItemReader interface. For example:

```
public MyReader implements ItemReader<YourClass> {


  @Override
  public YourClass read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {

    // Implement your read logic, return null when no more items

  }
}
```

this simple class will return your data and will just stop to read when all query data were retrieved,

I hope that it help you or other users :)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a list then you can just create an instance of [IteratorItemReader](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/IteratorItemReader.html).

```
List<MyClass> myClassList = myClassDao.list(...)
ItemReader reader = new IteratorItemReader(myClassList);
```

Comment: hm but I creating reader in applicationContext not in java code:     <bean id="registrujReader" class="cz.isvs.reg.rob.util.export.batch.RegistrujItemReader" parent="baseReader"
        scope="step" />. So how I can combine this two different things ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [ListItemReader](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ListItemReader.html)